# Obtaining Lorentz transformations in hyperbola geometry

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

In Tevian Dray's book *The Geometry of Special Relativity*, 1st edition, page 27, he writes:

> **5.3 Lorentz Transformations**
>
> We now relate Lorentz transformations, based on the physical postulates of special relativity, to hyperbola geometry. The Lorentz transformation between a frame $(x,t)$ at rest and a frame $(x',t')$ moving to the right at speed $v$ was derive in Chapter 2. The transformation from the moving frame to the rest frame is given by
> \begin{align}
> x &= \gamma (x' + v t'), \tag{5.1} \\
> t &= \gamma \left(t' + \frac{v}{c^2} x'\right), \tag{5.2} 
> \end{align}
> where, as before,
> $$\gamma = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}. \tag{5.3}$$
> The key to converting this description to hyperbola geometry is to measure space and time in the same units by replacing $t$ by $ct$. The transformation from the moving frame, which we now denote by $(x',ct')$, to the frame at rest, now denoted $(x,ct)$, is given by
> \begin{align}
> x &= \gamma \left(x' + \frac{v}{c} ct'\right), \tag{5.4} \\
> ct &= \gamma \left(ct' + \frac{v}{c} x'\right), \tag{5.5} 
> \end{align}
> which makes the symmetry between these equations much more obvious.

I understand that he obtained 5.4 from 5.1 by changing $t'$ to $ct'$ and $v$ to $v/c$. But by substituting $v$ for $v/c$ in 5.2, wouldn't I obtain $(v/c^3)x'$ in 5.5? I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/168783), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead. I edited your question to adhere to these standards.

Comment: Thank you for editing and apologies for posting the image, I was unaware of that rule.

Comment: Your $\gamma$ is missing the \sqrt .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to redefine variables. It is just a matter of doing nothing with Eq. (5.1) and multiplying Eq. (5.2) by $c$. Notice that
$$vt' = \frac{v}{c} c t',$$
by pure algebra. Hence, Eq. (5.1) leads us to
\begin{align}
x &= \gamma (x' + v t'), \tag{5.1} \\
&= \gamma \left(x' + \frac{v}{c} ct'\right), \tag{5.4} 
\end{align}

Now, if we multiply Eq. (5.2) by $c$ we get
\begin{align}
t &= \gamma \left(t' + \frac{v}{c^2} x'\right), \tag{5.2} \\
ct &= \gamma \left(ct' + \frac{v}{c} x'\right). \tag{5.5} 
\end{align}